# Using NOT IN for multiple columns in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table which will have data following way

**id, email, filename**

1, abc,  file1

2, abc,  file1

1, abc,  file2

1, abc,  file3

---

I need unique users filename wise.

I need a query in a way that data containing in a file should not contain in other files.

Ex:

file1 has two different ids in that case it will have 2 unique users.

file2 data is same a file1 data so the unique users count should be 0

file3 has a different email so it should have 1 unique user

A file should have atleast id or email different from other files to calculate it as a unique user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also why is MySQL and clickhouse both tagged? Those are conflicting RDMS tags..

Comment: Why does file1 have 2 unique users and file2 has 0? Couldn't we also say that file1 has 1 unique user (because the other one already exists in file2) and file2 has also 1?

Comment: It's a step by step process. First file1 data will be inserted at that time file2 data will not present so that file1 will have 2 unique users.

Comment: So you want to insert a new filename's records into the table and then see how many new unique users it has?